# How is the helicopter throttle control connected to the transmission system?

Tags: helicopter

Both the throttle control and the transmission system regulate the rotor blade RPM but how are they connected to each other or are they different from each other.

Comment: The transmission is just a transmission. It doesn't regulate speed.  It's not like a car; there is only one gear ratio and the only clutch is a sprag clutch that lets it freewheel when power is removed.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what you think the impact of the Transmission is?

Comment: Typically (in the case of piston-engined helicopters) the throttle isn’t connected to anything except the carburettor of the engine.  It’s immediate function is to restrict the amount of air getting into the cylinders, indirectly the amount of fuel and the power output of the engine, and this combines with rotor pitch etc to determine rotor speed and ultimately lift.

Answer (score 2):

The transmission ratio is designed to get the best operating speed for the main rotor to coincide with the best power operating point for the engine. This is done by choosing the amount of gear-down to, for example, obtain 800 RPM on the main rotor while the engine is governed to run at 2400 RPM.

Then, when the pilot pulls up on the collective, the governor (if the helo has one) commands the throttle to maintain 2400 engine RPM as the main rotor torque load increases- and the helo takes off with the engine running at 2400 RPM, at the peak of its power curve (or near it). Otherwise the pilot advances the throttle manually to maintain rotor speed.

Comment: @jim, will edit.